# Finding the volume of a frustum

Tags: calculus, volume

I do know how to find this in a different way, I do not understand **why this isn't working**, however. Thank you for your time!
The volume should be $\frac{\pi h}{3}*(r_2^2+r_2r_1+r_1^2)$
$$r_2-r_1\text{ corresponds to }\Delta z=h\text{ not }H$$
[image]

Comment: Should be $r=\frac{R}{H}\zeta$

Comment: I do not think so, it is $\frac{r_2}{H}$

Comment: The result is $\pi \frac{R^2}{h^2}(H^3 - (H-h)^3)$. Then simply use the fact that $r_1 \frac{h}{R} = (H-h)$ and $r_2 \frac{h}{R} = (H)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume by discs
$$dV= \pi r^2 dz$$

$$ \frac{r}{z}= \tan \alpha$$

$$ dV= \pi r^2 d( r/ \tan \alpha)$$

$$ V=\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\pi r^2 d( r/ \tan \alpha) =\frac{\pi}{3} (r_2^3-r_1^3)/\tan \alpha$$re
where
$$\tan \alpha= \frac{r_2-r_1}{h}$$
Plug in and result follows:
$$ V=\frac{\pi h}{3}(r_1^2+r_2^2+r_1 r_2)$$

Comment: Hello Narasimham! I am asking about the fault in my integration.

Comment: It should be at start $\dfrac{R}{H}=\dfrac{r}{z},$ integration is ok.

Comment: No! $R=r_2-r_1$ which correspond to $\Delta z=h$.

Comment: Oh, sorry my error.

Comment: It is ok, thank you for your solution anyhow :)

Comment: In last step convert everything to $r,$ show one more step then $H$ will be out.

Comment: yeah actually, I was doing $(H-(H-h))^3$ not $H^3-(H-h)^3$